# laravel asks for routes though the route exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have RestaurantController with these **methods**:

```
save
show($id)
```

when I finish executing the `save` method, I want to redirect the user to the `show($id)` method.

I tried this:

```
return Redirect::route('show', array($restaurant->id));
```

but I got :

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [/show] not defined.
```

I also tried this:

```
 NotFoundHttpException
```

though the `show` method exists.

in my routes.php I have:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

could you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route is the name of the route, so in this instance it'd be:

```
return Redirect::route('restaurants.show', [$restaurant->id]);
```

[See here for more information regarding redirects.](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects)

Also, just fyi, from the command line you can run `php artisan routes` to see a full list of routes and their corresponding names.

Comment: Coooool, it works. you the best. +1, I will accept your answer when the system allows.

Comment: please could you tell me please where can I change the logo of the project? the project logo is the xampp logo

Comment: I ment where it is located on the project so I can change it ?

Comment: In the `public` folder of your project @AnastasieLaurent :-)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha there is no logo in my public folder